# Time Difference calculation for python 3 - with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to make some calculations in regards of date and time. This is my scenario

```
import datetime

#variables
datetimeFormat='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

TimeIn='2016-04-16 9:10:58'
TimeOut='2016-04-16 14:16:42'

#First 3 hours rent charge

Rate1=40

#Every Succeeding hour rent charge

Succ_Rate=20

diff=datetime.datetime.strptime(TimeOut,datetimeFormat)\
    -datetime.datetime.strptime(TimeIn,datetimeFormat)


print("Time in was in,TimeIn, "was Time out at ",Timeout)

print("Difference:",diff)

print("Minutes",diff.seconds//60)

print("Rental Fee:,Rate1) *#Output current is 40*

print("Succeeding Fee:",Succ_rate) *#Output should be 40 for two hours succeeding*

print("Total Amount to be paid:,Rate1+Succ_rate) *#Output is 80*
```

Output that I need is whenever condition1 is true (3 hours rate will take effect) plus every Succeeding hour will take affect as well.

Comment: You can compute the number of elapsed hours, right?  So, `rent = Rate`, `if hours > 3:` `rent += Succ_Rate * (hours-3)`.  Right?

Comment: Thanks to the idea Tim Roberts, will try first